# How can I "condense" this code?

Tags: python, variables, global

I'm new to python, so I'm probably using the incorrect terminology, but how would I "condense" this code?

```
            for i in self.letterWord[0:1]:
                    if i == letter:
                            self.binaryWord[0] = 1

            for i in self.letterWord[1:2]:
                    if i == letter:
                            self.binaryWord[1] = 1

            for i in self.letterWord[2:3]:
                    if i == letter:
                            self.binaryWord[2] = 1
```

Would it look something like this?

```
            for i in self.letterWord[i:i+1]:
                    if i == letter:
                            self.binaryWord[i]=1
```

I tried using the code above but it keeps saying

```
local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Then, when I type in `global i`, it says

```
global name 'i' not defined
```

Hey guys! Thanks for all the responses! Sorry for the vague information, so thanks for answering my question anyways.

Comment: Use four spaces for indention.

Comment: Tell me, what is the value of `i` in this expression `for i in self.letterWord[i:i+1]`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: `self.binaryWord[2] = 1` What is the `binaryWord`? You know that string in python is immutable data type?

Comment: `self.letterWord[i:i+1]` in this part of code variable `i` isn't define. Sorry, but what are you trying to do? I try loop one letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with

```
for i in self.letterWord[i:i+1]:
    if i == letter:
        self.binaryWord[i]=1
```

is that `i` needs to be looked up to evaluate `self.letterWord[i:i+1]` before `i` is used as the list iterator, so that is the source of the error.

Try something like this:

```
for i, ltr in enumerate(self.letterWord):
    if ltr == letter:
        self.binaryWord[i] = 1
```

or even better (if possible, to create `self.binaryWord` in one line of code)

```
self.binaryWord = [ 1 if ltr == letter else 0 for ltr in self.letterWord ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with your existing setup, purely to condense the code, you could do:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(self.letterWord[:3]):
    if val == letter:
        self.binaryWord[idx] = 1
```

Although it's possible that you could use other methods to build these objects such as list-comps/zipping them together/etc...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your suggested code uses `i` to mean two different things. If anything, it would be:

```
    for l in self.letterWord[i:i+1]:
        if l == letter:
            self.binaryWord[i]=1
```

But also, self.letterWord[0:1] is going to contain exactly one item: self.letterWord[0]. Or nothing if it's out of range. So you don't need these for loops at all.

```
    if len(self.letterWord) < i and self.letterWord[i] == letter:
        self.binaryWord[i] = 1
```

You changed it to use i for the index; does that mean there is an outer loop? If you're looping over the length of letterWord, you don't need the len check I added.

```
for i in range(len(self.letterWord)):
    if self.letterWord[i] == letter:
        self.binaryWord[i] = 1
```

Also, looping over the indexes of a list isn't best practice, use `enumerate` if you need the index.

```
for i, l in enumerate(self.letterWord):
    if l == letter:
        self.binaryWord[i] = 1
```

And if you're just now creating binaryWord (you don't show how it's created), you could just create it as a list comprehension:

```
self.binaryWord = [int(l == letter) for l in self.letterWord]
# int(True) is 1, int(False) is 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One row solution

```
self.binaryWord = "%s%s" % (self.binaryWord[:3].replace(letter, "1"), self.binaryWord[3:])
```

And if you want change all letters in row you can do somethinf like this

```
self.binaryWord = self.binaryWord.replace(letter, "1")
```